# HorizontalGauge causes problem with ScalingFunctions -> "Log"

Tags: bugs, gui-construction

**Bug introduced in 9.0.0 and persisting through 12.2.0 or later**

*`HorizontalGauge` is new in 9.0.0*

---

I am trying to use `HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[expt], {0.1, 100}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]`, i.e. a gauge with a logarithmic scale.  This creates an error, a graph with a pink background.

Monitoring the output with `Dynamic[expt]` and a second gauge

`HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[expt], {0.1, 100}, ScalingFunctions -> None]`

indicates that the logarithmic `HorizontalGauge` actually generates the expected output.  Unless, somebody realizes a mistake in this rather simple code, I must assume this is a bug in Mathematica 9.

**EDIT**

Unluckily, this error has not been corrected in version 9.0.1

```
... , ScalingFunctions -> {Exp, Log}
```

sort of works, but the locations of the tick marks are of course wrong.  In the other order `{Log, Exp}` the error from above is reproduced.  I reported this as an error.

Comment: I can't get *any* `ScalingFunction` to work correctly.  Even `#^2&` or `Sqrt` break moving the slider (though the display is correct).  But where is this option documented for gauges? I could only find it for charts.

Comment: For `ThermometerGauge` it is mentioned in the documentation, and it's also badly broken (you can mention this when writing support as it doesn't seem to be a well documented option).  I guess you're right and this is a bug.  Also, `Sqrt[#]&` behaves differently from `Sqrt`.

Comment: It's not listed in the examples in the "Option" section. I suppose that is a sign of some kind.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries but, it is listed in `Options@HorizontalGauge` so it should work. I'll look into it, but it may be a few days.

Comment: It does not work on `AngularGauge` too!..