# ScalingFunctions not working properly for x-axis

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make a chart where the x-axis has a log scale and the y-axis is in reverse order. I tried to use `LogLinearPlot`, and I tried to combine it with `ScalingFunctions`. My code was:

```
LogLinearPlot[1/x, {x, 1, 1000}, ScalingFunctions->"Reverse"]
```

But this failed. So I tried using `Plot` and `ScalingFunctions`:

```
Plot[1/x, {x, 1, 1000}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Reverse"}]
```

That gave me an error as well. I noticed that `ScalingFunctions` works just fine when applied to the y-axis, as in:

```
Plot[1/x, {x, 1, 1000}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
Plot[1/x, {x, 1, 1000}, ScalingFunctions->"Reverse"]
```

However, when I apply `ScalingFunctions` to the x-axis, it will give an error; for example:

```
Plot[1/x, {x, 1, 1000}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", Identity}]
```

Can anyone tell me what to do to get a reversed y-axis and a logarithmic x-axis at the same time?

Comment: I mentioned a problem with ScalingFunctions in "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16557/horizontalgauge-causes-problem-with-scalingfunctions-log" and reported a bug to Wolfram.  This might be a more serious issue.

Answer (score 10):

*At least in v8*, the following:

```
Reap@Plot[1/x, {x, 1, 1000}, ScalingFunctions -> (Sow@## &)]
```

reveals that the only argument passed to `ScalingFunctions` is the `y` coordinate. So, it wont scale the `x` axis.

But instead you may post-process the ticks generated by default:

```
k[f_] := Show[#, AbsoluteOptions[#, Ticks] /. {x_, x_, y__} :> {x, -x, y}] &@
                                                                LogLinearPlot[-f[x], {x, 1, 1000}]
f[x_] := 1/x;
k[f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]